# PHP convert array to serialized string suitable as an array key

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, key

I have several associative arrays in PHP that looks like this:

```
$data1 = array("foo" => "one", "animal" => "mice");
$data2 = array("foo" => "two", "animal" => "cats");
....
```

I want to create another associative array, using the serialized values of the previous arrays are used as the array keys. For example:

```
$newArray = array("data1's serialized key" => "someNewValue", ... );
```

Are serialized arrays suitable for being used as array keys?

Do they contain any unacceptable characters?

Do I need to do something more to the serialized string to make it acceptable as an array key (while still keeping its uniqueness)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are serialized arrays suitable for being used as array keys?

Yup! As far as I know you can use serialized arrays as a key in another array. But the I cannot think of any use-case for this. :P

> Do they contain any unacceptable characters?

No, until and unless you specify any unacceptable characters in the original array.

> Do I need to do something more to the serialized string to make it acceptable as an array key (while still keeping its uniqueness)?

Nope.

So, you code would look like:

```
$data1 = array("foo" => "one", "animal" => "mice");
$data2 = array("foo" => "two", "animal" => "cats");
$serializedArrayKey1 = serialize($data1);
$serializedArrayKey2 = serialize($data2);
$newArray = array($serializedArrayKey1 => "Value for data1", ...);
```